# AngularJS version 1.6 change from `.success` method to `.then` method

Tags: angularjs, angular-http, angularjs-1.6

actually am following a spring tutorial .. coming to Angularjs he is using .succes

```
var app=angular.module("MyApp",[]);
.controller("MyController",function($scope,$http){
    $scope.pageProduits=null;

    $http.get("http://localhost:8080/chercherProduits?mc")
    .success(function(data){
         $scope.pageProduits=data;
    })
    .error(function(err){
         console.log(err);
    });

});
```

now my problem is that success is not working and after searshing i descovered that The .success and .error methods are deprecated and have been removed from AngularJS 1.6. i have to the standard .then method instead.
Can someone convert me the existing code to code with the then mothod ? i tried but i failed can anyone helps plz bcz am not familiar with javaScript ? 
Thank you

Comment: .then(response) => .catch(error) => .finally()

Answer (score 4):

### Before

```
$http(...).success(function onSuccess(data, status, headers, config) {
  // Handle success
  //...
}).error(function onError(data, status, headers, config) {
  // Handle error
  //...
});
```

### After

```
$http(...).then(function onSuccess(response) {
    // Handle success
    var data = response.data;
    var status = response.status;
    var statusText = response.statusText;
    var headers = response.headers;
    var config = response.config;
    //...
  }).catch(function onError(response) {
    // Handle error
    var data = response.data;
    var status = response.status;
    var statusText = response.statusText;
    var headers = response.headers;
    var config = response.config;
    //...
  });
```

For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Migrating from V1.5 to V1.6](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#migrate1.5to1.6-ng-services-$http)

See also, [Why are angular $http success/error methods deprecated? Removed from v1.6?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35331339/5535245)

Answer (score 1):

use `then` like this to catch the response.
make sure to use `response.data` because response data comes under `data` property

```
$http.get("http://localhost:8080/chercherProduits?mc")
.then(function(response){
     $scope.pageProduits=response.data;
},function(response){
     console.log(response.data);
})
```

use `ng repeat` to show the data in row wise

```
<body ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyController">
   <div class="container">
      <table class="table table-striped">
         <thead>
            <tr >
               <th>ID</th>
               <th>Désignation</th>
               <th>Prix</th>
               <th>Quantité</‌​th> 
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="p in pageProduits">
               <td>{{p.id}}</td>
               <td>{{p.designation}}</td>
               <td>{{p.prix}}</td>
               <td>{{p.quantite}}</td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </div>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/angular/angular.min.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script> 
</body>
```

Comment: thank u sachila `var app=angular.module("MyApp",[]);
app.controller("MyController",function($scope,$http){
 $scope.pageProduits=null;
 $http.get("http://localhost:8080/chercherProduits?mc")
 .then(function(resonse){
      $scope.pageProduits=resonse.data;
 },function(resonse){
      console.log(resonse.data);
 })
});`

Comment: ..........
</head>
<body ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyController">
<div class="container">
<table class="table table-striped">
<thead>
 <tr>
  <th>ID</th><th>Désignation</th><th>Prix</th><th>Quantité</th>
 </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

 <tr >
  <td>{{p.id}}</td>
  <td>{{p.designation}}</td>
  <td>{{p.prix}}</td>
  <td>{{p.quantite}}</td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
</body></html>`

Comment: but the result is not showing :( no errors like before with the js fine but i cannot see the rows like in the tertorial.. can u help me ?

Comment: yesss sachila ^__^ just ng-repeat="p in pageProduits.content" not only ng-repeat="p in pageProduits". bcz in that page (json) there are lots of informations abut the page produit "totalPages": 24,
"totalElements": 120,
"last": false,
"size": 5,
"number": 0,
"sort": null,
"numberOfElements": 5,
"first": true .. "content" is the need and thaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaankkkk youuuuuu

Comment: No prob. Make sure to mark as answer if this helped

Answer (score 0):

The AngularJS `$http` service makes a request to the server, and returns a `response`.Use `then` instead of `success` like below:

```
var app=angular.module("MyApp",[]);
app.controller("MyController",function($scope,$http){
$scope.pageProduits=null;

$http.get("http://localhost:8080/chercherProduits?mc")
.then(function(data){  // function that execute on ajax success
     $scope.pageProduits=data.data;
}, function error(function(err){  //function that execute on ajax error
     console.log(err.statusText);
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As per angular Js official documentations. `Success` and `error` methods are no longer available. These methods are depreciated instead they recommend to use standard `.then` method. `Succces` methods return only the `data` from the response but in `.then` method, full `response` object is returned.

```
var app=angular.module("MyApp",[])
.controller("MyController",function($scope,$http){
    $scope.pageProduits=null;

    $http.get("http://localhost:8080/chercherProduits?mc")
    .then(function(response){
         if(response.status === 200) {
             $scope.pageProduits=response.data
         }
    }, function(error) {
        console.log(error)
    });
});
```

For More Info: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http